# Updating multiple embedded document not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I have a table with data like

```
 {
  _id: ....
  Name
  ...
 "RoomStatusDetails": [
 {
   "StatusEntryId": ObjectId("5bd6ea81d2ccda0a780054da"),
   "RoomId": "78163a07-76db-83c1-5c22-0749fab73251",
   "CurrentStatus": ObjectId("5bd17295d2ccda11f0007765"),
   "StartDate": ISODate("2018-10-09T22:00:00.0Z"),
   "Notes": "Notes for in service",
   "Discrepancy": "Discrepency",
   "Waiver": "Waiver",
   "TFlight": "T Flight",
   "IsActive": "Inactive" 
},
 {
   "StatusEntryId": ObjectId("5bd6ecf3d2ccda0a780054db"),
   "RoomId": "78163a07-76db-83c1-5c22-0749fab73251",
   "CurrentStatus": ObjectId("5bd17295d2ccda11f0007766"),
   "StartDate": ISODate("2018-10-16T22:00:00.0Z"),
   "Notes": "Out of service",
   "Discrepancy": "",
   "Waiver": "",
   "TFlight": "",
   "IsActive": "Active" 
    },
    ...
   }
```

I have written below lines of code for updating  IsActive field to  "Inactive" on the basis of RoomId

```
       $this->collection->updateOne(array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id), "RoomStatusDetails" => 
                  array('$elemMatch' => array("RoomId" => $this->RoomId))),
                  array('$set' => array("RoomStatusDetails.$.IsActive" => 'Inactive')), array("multi" => true, "upsert" => false));
```

The above code is not updating all the IsActive field. Please help!!!

Comment: Use `update` method instead of `updateOne`.

Comment: it does not work .. it throws undefined method update and i m using 3.6. Even if i use updateMany, it does not throw any error message but it does not update other embedded documents

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Paste error while using `update`.

Comment: Use `$[]` instead of `$`. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/update/positional-all/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### All matched embedded document:

For updating all matched embedded documents you should use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) because [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/update/positional/) refer the first position of matched embedded document.

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element
>   that matches the query document

Comment: thankyou so much....

Comment: @NidaAmin Most welcome!

Comment: after completing certain things i realised that it is not updating on the basis of roomid... it is updating other rooms status to inactive... please help

Comment: / Add new if status changes
            $bulkbatchStatus = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => true]);

            $bulkbatchStatus->update(array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id), "RoomStatusDetails" => 
                      array('$elemMatch' => array("RoomId" => $this->RoomId))),
                      array('$set' => array("RoomStatusDetails.$[].IsActive" => 'Inactive')), array("multi" => true, "upsert" => false));

Comment: If you want specific matched but multiple documents then check Veeram answer.

Comment: I tried that it also does not work... please help!!

Comment: it throws  Call to undefined method MongoDB\Collection::update() in

Answer (score 2):

You have to use arrayFilters to pass in the room id filter. 
Without arrayFilters it will update all `[]` the "RoomStatusDetails" array elements without taking into account the room id query filter.

Something like

```
 db.col.update(
   {"RoomStatusDetails.RoomId" :"78163a07-76db-83c1-5c22-0749fab73251"},
   {"$set":{"RoomStatusDetails.$[room].IsActive" : "Inactive"}}, 
   {"arrayFilters":{"room.RoomId":"78163a07-76db-83c1-5c22-0749fab73251"}}
);
```

In php

```
$bulkbatchStatus->update(
  array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id), "RoomStatusDetails" => array('$elemMatch' => array("RoomId" => $this->RoomId))), 
  array('$set' => array("RoomStatusDetails.$[room].IsActive" => 'Inactive')), 
  array("multi" => true, "upsert" => false, "arrayFilters" => array("room.RoomId" => $this->RoomId))
);
```

Comment: It does not work and does not throw any error message...

Comment: Can you show me your query ?

Comment: $bulkbatchStatus = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => true]);
$bulkbatchStatus->update(
  array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id), "RoomStatusDetails" => array('$elemMatch' => array("RoomId" => $this->RoomId))), 
  array('$set' => array("RoomStatusDetails.$[room].IsActive" => 'Inactive')), 
  array("multi" => true, "upsert" => false, "arrayFilters" => array("room.RoomId" => $this->RoomId))
);

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the query. Can you make sure the passed arguments are correct  and have a matching document meeting the query criteria in db ?

Comment: the arguments are passed correctly....

Comment: Did you update your mongo server recently ? What is your mongo server version ? You may have to run `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: 3.6 } )` on mongo shell if you updated from 3.4 to 3.6.

Comment: i am using 3,6 version

Comment: Please help !!! it is very difficult to analyse the problrm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182741/discussion-between-veeram-and-nida-amin).

Comment: Any luck with the issue ?